# elastic: query the sum of a filtered subset of nested documents

Tags: elasticsearch

Consider a document (post) like this in elasticsearch index:

```
    {
      title: "I love ice cream!"
      comments: [
        {
          body: "me too!",
          reaction: 'positive',
          likes: 20
        },
        {
          body: "huh!",
          reaction: 'sarcastic',
          likes: 5
        }
      ]
    }
```

The comments is a field of `nested` type.

How can elastic answer this:
Give me all posts, where the total sum of likes on "sarcastic" comments is greater than 100.
I'm open to any other way of modelling data which helps answer such queries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved using [bucket selector aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html).

Mapping:

```
{
  "index1" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "properties" : {
        "comments" : {
          "type" : "nested",
          "properties" : {
            "body" : {
              "type" : "text"
            },
            "likes" : {
              "type" : "integer"
            },
            "reaction" : {
              "type" : "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "title" : {
          "type" : "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data:

```
  "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "index1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "p0y9DGsBfPdKzuAGdQrm",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "I love ice cream!",
          "comments" : [
            {
              "body" : "me too!",
              "reaction" : "positive",
              "likes" : 20
            },
            {
              "body" : "huh!",
              "reaction" : "sarcastic",
              "likes" : 5
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "_index" : "index1",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "qEy9DGsBfPdKzuAGnwox",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "title" : "I hate ice cream!",
          "comments" : [
            {
              "body" : "me too!",
              "reaction" : "positive",
              "likes" : 10
            },
            {
              "body" : "huh!",
              "reaction" : "sarcastic",
              "likes" : 5
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Query:

```
GET index1/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "title": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "title"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "comments": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "comments"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "reaction": {
              "filter": {
                "term": {
                  "comments.reaction": "positive"
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "total_likes": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "comments.likes"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "total_likes_filter": {
          "bucket_selector": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "likes": "comments>reaction>total_likes"
            },
            "script": "params.likes > 15"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "title" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 0,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "I love ice cream!",
          "doc_count" : 1,
          "comments" : {
            "doc_count" : 2,
            "reaction" : {
              "doc_count" : 1,
              "total_likes" : {
                "value" : 20.0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Bucket contains only "I love ice cream!" where total likes for reaction positive  is greater than 20.
I hate ice cream! has total sum 5 for positive reaction so it is not included.

Comment: Is it necessary to make the mapping nested? Also, he asked to filter on `reaction`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have updated answer with reaction filter. I am not able to think of a way of doing it without making comment as nested object, since it has to be filtered on reaction

Comment: Thanks @jaspreetchahal we implemented something very similar in our production!